# create linked entities in EF based on automatically generated id

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Challenge in EF6:

how to check Id of resulting row in the database after running this (esentially adding an entity record):

```
repository.Add(myEntity1);
```

...and use that id to add the second entity which has property X = to the id of the first entity?

use that id to add the second entity which has property X = to the id of the first entity?

```
repository.Add(myEntity2);
```

Right now there is no linkage between entity 1 and entity 2 because i don;t know how to save the id (automatically generated by ef) after first add 
... and preserve it for adding it as a fk in the second entity?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not offering a definitive answer because I am not certain as I have a .NET Core 2.1 solution and not an EF 6 close by.  But I believe you can extend your 'Add' to have 'Entity' and it gets the info on the object after 'save changes' is called.  like 'var object = context.Object.Add(input).Entity;  context.SaveChanges(); var id = object.YourId'.  Your initial 'input' object may also have this value after SaveChanges but I also cannot recall as I set up a GUID in the constructor of my object and I am guessing your a using an identity insert with an int.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this following after your call to `SaveChanges`:

```
myEntity2.X = myEntity1.Id;
```

Then call `SaveChanges` again. This doesn't really utilise the power of Entity Framework, however, which is in managing relationships between entities. If your class was defined something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RelatedEntity))]
    public int RelatedEntityId { get; set; }
    public MyEntity RelatedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

You could add your entities something like the following, and the Id/foreign key matching would be handled for you after calling `SaveChanges`:

```
myEntity1.RelatedEntity = myEntity2;
```

This is a fairly general solution, so if you'd like something more specific then you will need to include more details in your question.

You can read more about configuring Entity Framework relationships [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx).